# how to generate histogram/ frequency count in ggplot: weird behavior

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

This might be an easy question for regular ggplot users, but I'm running into some unexpected behavior between `ggplot` and `qplot` and I don't understand the reason.

I'm trying to plot a simple histogram with counts. This works well with `qplot`:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,3,4,5)
qplot(x)
```

[image: samplepic]

However, when I try to achieve the same result using `ggplot`, I get the following error message. Any suggestions of what might be the problem?

```
ggplot(data=x, aes(x)) + geom_histogram()
Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class numeric
```

Comment: It expects a data.frame: `ggplot(data = data.frame(x = x), aes(x)) + geom_histogram()` Please study the documentation.

Comment: @smci. I think that you might be right but I am not sure. I think that it is a case where the question is different from that post ("How to plot frequency...") but you are right in that the answer to both posts is the same.

Comment: @SolLago: both questions are asking *How to plot the (histogram/) frequency count of a vector with ggplot?*, although their titles use different terms. You are correct that not all users will infer "histogram" from "frequency" let alone "frequency count". I will go add *"histogram/ frequency count"* to that question's title to canonicalize it. Now these questions are exact duplicates.

Comment: @smci: good idea. I followed your suggestion and marked it as duplicate!

Comment: Yes, it's a community-run site, each of us can do stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a weird behaviour: `ggplot2` simply operates on `data.frame` objects - and not vectors:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,3,4,5)), aes(x=x)) + geom_histogram()
```

[image]